# How can I run WSL commands from Emacs running on Windows?

Tags: microsoft-windows, eshell, wsl

There are tons of articles on how to install GNU Emacs on WSL(2) and how to work within WSL2. However, I have Emacs installed on Windows<sup>1</sup> and would like to access the file system and commands within WSL from my Windows' Emacs installation and not bother with another installation in WSL.

I can access the filesystem via `M-x dired \\wsl.localhost\\<Distribution>\\`, but I'm not able to actually connect my (e)shell with WSL and run, for example, `uname`. Is that possible, maybe via TRAMP or similar?

**TL;DR:** How can I run commands *within* WSL from my *Windows* Emacs installation?

<sup>1: GNU Emacs 28.2 (build 2, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2022-09-13, in case an answer is depending on the version</sup>

Comment: Addendum: seems like the file access is flaky. Emacs just crashed when I tried to access the WSL files for the third time :(